# Detaching UA subscriptions

Tags: benchmarks

I'm trying to make a demo with hardened linux VM machines

I'm using UA with my personal subscription to install the hardening profile level 1 server. However, because I'm making an image on my own virtualizing software. Can I just detach it and cancel the contact?

Warm regards,
tangtang

Comment: `ua detach` will work on the machine to disconnect it from UA

Answer (score 0):

Just run `ua detach` on the machine before using it as a base image.  That should be sufficient to 'detach' from Ubuntu Advantage before provisioning machines.